# Appending New Values to a Durable Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a linked list using the durable constructor method described in Nicholas Zakas' book but I am running into a conceptual problem.

I understand that the durable constructor pattern is used for security reasons and eschews the use of "this" and "new." However, I am unsure if that means I am unable to create methods that allow for appending nodes to the linked list.

All of the instances I've found have basically been taken straight from Douglas Crockford with really no variation. The example he uses only retrieves information from the object.

My questions are: Does this constructor pattern allow appending data to such data structures? If it doesn't and Crockford says we need to avoid "this" and "new" what options do I have?

edit (linked list code so far):

```
var linkedList = function (spec) {
    var that = {};

    that.addNode = function (newNode) {
        if (spec.size && spec.root) {
            // not sure
        } else {
            // not sure yet
        }
    };

    that.getRoot = function () {
        return spec.root; // for an idea of how to retrieve
    };

    return that;
};

// how I'd like to use the list
var firstNode = node({val: 25, next: null});
var myList = linkedList({root: firstNode, size: 1});
var secondNode = node({val: 33, next: null});
myList.add(secondNode); // I feel this isn't possible
```

Comment: May I have a look of your linked-lists' code? I don't have the book you mentioned.

Comment: I added my work in progress so far.

Comment: What's spec.size is use for? And in your code `that = {};` would reference out the scope , possilbly `window`, so it's equal to  `window.that = {}` unless you have define the `that` before.

Comment: spec.size would hopefully be the size of the list, but I'm not sure that would be appropriate. An instantiation of this linkedList would look something like: `var myList = linkedList({root: someNode, size: 1});`

Comment: @fuyushimoya Good catch on the scope issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still quite not sure about the durable object, but I think what you want to do might be this:

```
var LinkedList = function(val) {
  // A private object
  var node = {
    val: val,
    next : null
  };

  // Method
  var getVal = function() {
    return node.val;
  };
  var setVal = function(val) {
    node.val = val;
  };
  var getNext = function() {
    return node.next;
  };
  var setNext = function(newNode) {
    // You have to ensure its a node here
    if (true) {
      node.next = newNode;
    }
  };
  // Append to tail
  var appendVal = function(val) {
    if (node.next === null) {
      node.next = LinkedList(val);
    } else {
      node.next.appendVal(val);
    }
  };
  var appendNode = function(newNode) {
    if (node.next === null) {
      node.next = newNode
    } else {
      node.next.appendNode(newNode);
    }
  };
  var print = function() {
    var str = '' + node.val;
    if (node.next !== null) {
      str += ' => ' + node.next.print();
    }
    return str;
  }

  // Only expose method to user.
  return {
    getVal : getVal,
    setVal : setVal,
    getNext: getNext,
    appendVal: appendVal,
    appendNode: appendNode,
    print: print
  };
};
```

When we want a root, call `var root = LinkedList(val);` Then the function will create a hidden object, set the value, and return methods that is able to get/set the object the value for you.
You can do things only with the exposed object, and in this way, the `this` and `new` is avoided, and you get a private object that can't be accessed directly.

And what you want to do may be write like this:

```
var first = LinkedList(25);
var myList = LinkedList(null);
myList.appendNode(first);
var second = LinkedList(33);
myList.appendNode(second);
console.log(myList.print());  // null => 25 => 33
```

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting! I've learned a lot about javascript from this code. Can you please explain the the `appendVal` method in a bit of detail? It seems we are connecting a linked list to a newly instantiated linked list. Thank you!

Comment: The `appendVal` just combine 2 things to 1, like `a.appendVal(2)` is somehow equal to `var b = LinkList(2); a.appendNode(b);` just for convenience that sometimes we are so lazy that we don't want to write 2 lines to do this thing.